# Subtract values from different groups

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    A   X
Time        
1   a   10
2   b   17
3   b   20
4   c   21
5   c   36
6   d   40
```

given by `pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'A': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd'], 'X': [10, 17, 20, 21, 36, 40]}).set_index('Time')`

The desired output is:

```
Time    Difference
0   2   7
1   4   1
2   6   4
```

The first difference `1` is a result of subtracting `21` from `20`: (first `"c"` value - last `"b"` value).

I'm open to `numPy` transformations as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html),
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) and then subtract shifted values for `last` column with omit first row by positions:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df1 = df.groupby('A',as_index=False, sort=False).agg(first=('X', 'first'),
                                                     last=('X','last'),
                                                     Time=('Time','first'))

df1['Difference'] = df1['first'].sub(df1['last'].shift(fill_value=0))

df1 = df1[['Time','Difference']].iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
   Time  Difference
0     2           7
1     4           1
2     6           4
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the columns, and compute the difference:

```
g = df.reset_index().groupby('A')

(df.assign(col=g.cumcount().values)
   .pivot('A', 'col', 'X')
   .ffill(axis=1)
   .assign(Time=g['Time'].first(),
           diff=lambda d: d[0]-d[1].shift())
   [['Time', 'diff']].iloc[1:]
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

output:

```
   Time  Difference
b     2         7.0
c     4         1.0
d     6         4.0
```

Intermediate, pivoted/ffilled dataframe:

```
col     0     1  Time  Difference
A                                
a    10.0  10.0     1         NaN
b    17.0  20.0     2         7.0
c    21.0  36.0     4         1.0
d    40.0  40.0     6         4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mozway! I went with jezrael's as it's a bit easier to understand.

Comment: @Xavier no worries, pick the one you like

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(Y = df['X'].shift())
 .iloc[df.index % 2 == 0]
 .assign(Difference = lambda z: z['X'] - z['Y'])
 .reset_index()
 .loc[:, ['Time', 'Difference']]
)
```

Output:

```
   Time  Difference
0     2         7.0
1     4         1.0
2     6         4.0
```